# redirect method isn't redirecting me to the required page(/SignIn) instead of this it leaves me in the same page but make it (/updateinfo?)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, axios, mern

I'm using window.location to redirect to the signin page after changing the user info but for some reason it's not redirecting me but it takes me to the same page (/updateinfo) but changes the url to (/updateinfo?) or can anyone show me how to use push history please

```
onSubmit(e){
    // e.PreventDefault();
    console.log("1")
    const user = {
        Name : this.state.Name,
        Email : this.state.Email,
        Password : this.state.Password,
        Type : this.state.Type

    }
    console.log(user)
    console.log("1")
    axios.post('http://localhost:8000/Updateinfo', user)
    .then(res=>{
        window.location = '/SignIn';
      

    })
    
   

    console.log("didn't redirect !");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location.href = '/SignIn';
```

Comment: window.location.href  also didn't work

Comment: are you using React router ? if yes then you can redirect to signin page by using Navigate function